# The following code gives Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Tags: php

The following code gives `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE. on line 8`.

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    $password=$_REQUEST['password'];

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb");

    if(mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,"select*from user101 where 
    email="$email" and password="$password"")))
    {
        $_SESSION['email']=$email;
        echo "login successful";
        header("Location:welcome.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Login failed";
    }
?>
```

Comment: **Warning: Your code is _wide open_ to SQL injections** and you should use Prepared Statements instead of concatenating your queries like this.

Comment: **_Never_ store passwords in plain text.** Only store hashed passwords. Use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.

Comment: Another thing, you can't have an `echo` before you set the header. Headers needs to come before _any_ output. Echoing something before you redirect the user doesn't really make any sense anyway, since they won't be able to see it.

Comment: it would be great if you accepted one of the answers and flag helpful comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this because you had many double quotes and that is wrong.It should  be like this " 'var' 'var'  "

```
<?php 
session_start();
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
$password=$_REQUEST['password'];

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb");

if(mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,"select*from user101 where 
email='$email' and password='$password'")))
{
$_SESSION['email']=$email;
echo "login successful";
header("Location:welcome.php");
}
else
{
echo "Login failed";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write single quote in sqlstring solved this problem. But i suggest use mysql escape functions for prevent sql injections

```
<?php 
session_start();
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
$password=$_REQUEST['password'];

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb");

if(mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,"select*from user101 where 
email='$email' and password='$password'")))
{
$_SESSION['email']=$email;
echo "login successful";
header("Location:welcome.php");
}
else
{
echo "Login failed";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line number 8 with this -

```
if(mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,"select * from user101 where 
email='$email' and password= '$password'")))
```

I hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

It could be like this. avoid double quote inside the  query when using double quote in outside

```
mysqli_query($con,"select*from user101 where 
email='$email' and password='$password'")
```